# findafter with relation another table yii

Tags: php, yii

In my database I have 2 tables:

```
country(id,name)
users(id,countryid)

country ->id= users->countryid;
```

I'm trying to perform this task with yii relations to get name from country table :

users modals

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
        'linkedIndex' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Country','countryid'),
       );
    }
    public function afterFind()
    {
       $name = Users::model()->findByPk(1);
    }
```

Comment: What about your country modal ?

Answer (score 1):

if you look at this code closely, you will see that variable name is being populated,**BUT** after functions ends, the variable also gets destroyed,

```
public function afterFind()
{
   $name = Users::model()->findByPk(1);
}
```

if you want to keep this `$name`, you have to make it a property of the model class (or store it in an existing property)